# Number of perfect matchings in complete graph $K$ with $n$ nodes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I think when n is odd the answer is 0.
But when $n$ is even I don't know how to write this formula that I get.

Comment: define a perfect matching

Comment: When  you make pairs of nodes ,and spent all nodes

Comment: so if you have 3 nodes you would have 1 perfect matching right? like node 1 can match node 2

Comment: The graph with 3 nodes has not perfect matching ,because you can t spent all nodes

Comment: 4 nodes is 2 right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** fix a specified edge with its node, and compute recursive.

$$T(n) = (n-1)\times T(n-2) = (n-1)\times (n-3) \times \cdots \times 1 = \prod_{i=1}^{\frac{n}{2}}(n-2i+1)$$
$$T(2) = 1$$

$n$ is the number of nodes (Notice that, here $n$ is even).

Comment: Thats not true for example K³  has 0 perfect matchings

Comment: That s more better.thanks